# Match an HTML attribute using Regex/jQuery (for a search)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to initiate a search (or rather filter) on `keypress` for an image library. The user starts typing in the name of an image, and any image name that doesn't match the search term gets hidden:

```
<div id="abc" data-imgName="abc"></div>
<div id="abc2" data-imgName="abc2"></div>
<div id="xyz" data-imgName="xyz"></div>
```

So if a user starts typing in "ab", then: `$('#xyz').hide();`

How can I do this?  Can I use regex on an attribute?

Comment: You could use a regex, sure, but since it is only basic characters and the start of the string, why don't you just use a function to see if the string starts with the defined characters?

Comment: Do you need regex or is it sufficient just to look for an exact match?

Comment: hi @fge. regex so that "bc" hides "xyz" but not "abc2"

Comment: Well, no need, from the answers you have, it seems `.indexOf()` just fits the bill

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//bind an event handler to the text input for the keyup event (so the value will have changed by the time this event fires)
$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function (event) {

    //convert the value of the text box to lowercase
    this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();

    //cache the elements that match the search
    var good_to_go = $('[data-imgName*=' + $(this).val() + ']').show();

    //hide all the elements that do not match the search
    $('[data-imgName]').not(good_to_go).hide();
});
```

There is probably a way to do this that performs better but this takes the value of the text input and finds all the elements with the `data-imgName` attribute that contains the value of the text input. It then finds all the elements with the `data-imgName` attribute and hides all of the elements that have not been found already.

If you have a parent element to all of the searched elements, you should start all the selectors with it to avoid searching the entire DOM:

```
var $container = $('#container-id');
$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function (event) {
    this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();
    if (this.value == '') {
        $container.children().show();
    } else {
        var good_to_go = $container.find('[data-imgName*="' + this.value + '"]').show();
        $container.find('[data-imgName]').not(good_to_go).hide();
    }
});
```

Notice that this example also checks if the value of the text box is nothing, if so then it shows all of the searched elements.

Here are docs for the `*=` (contains) selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Here are docs for the `.not()` function: http://api.jquery.com/not

Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HRjHV/3/

Comment: I would also recommend doing it on keyup instead of keypress http://api.jquery.com/keyup/.

Comment: Funny, I just made that change, then when the post refreshed, there your comment is, good comment.

Comment: I would also make it `var good_to_go = $('[data-imgName*=' + $(this).val() + ']').show()`. That way hidden items will be shown again if the user backspaces and the query now matches that item.

Comment: @anstosa Excellent suggestion. I will update the code and example.

Comment: @Jasper, this is great! and getting better by the minute :) how bout case insensitivity? (since most search fields probably need that)

Comment: @Emile You can make the input lower-case by adding this line in the event handler: `this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();` answer updated

Comment: @Emile One last update for ya, I added some animation to the show/hide logic: http://jsfiddle.net/HRjHV/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#yourField').on('keyup', function() {
    $('.image').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('data-imgName').indexOf($('#yourField').val()) === -1) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit:** I'll leave this for reference but @Jasper's solution is much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

you have to cycle through all your divs each time, then its possible.

Adjust you html a little:

```
<div class="searchImg" data-imgName="abc"></div>
<div class="searchImg" data-imgName="abc2"></div>
<div class="searchImg" data-imgName="xyz"></div>
```

then you can cycle through them:

```
var searchTerm = "abc";
$("div.searchImg").each(function() {
   if($(this).attr("data-imgName").indexOf(searchTerm)) == -1)
     $(this).hide();
   else
     $(this).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="image_holder">
    <div id="abc" data-imgName="abc">a</div>
    <div id="abc2" data-imgName="abc2">b</div>
    <div id="xyz" data-imgName="xyz">x</div>
</div>

<br>

<input type="text" id="search">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#search").keyup(function() {

        var term = $(this).val();

        $("#image_holder").find("div").css("display", "block");

        $("#image_holder").find("div").each(function() {

            if ($(this).attr("data-imgName").indexOf(term) < 0) {

                $(this).css("display", "none");

            }

        });

    });

});
</script>
```

Here is a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/yASQW/